# iOS photo library

Tags: ios, photo

I am building an app that's a pre-install checklist for medical devices. I'd like to give the field reps the ability to use the camera so they can take pictures of the room(s) the device will be installed in. I've got the camera functioning fine and can show a thumbnail sheet of the images taken. What I would like to do is allow the user to select a thumbnail, provide a caption and store the selected image. By store, what I really mean is save a reference to that image in the photo library. So there would be a plist entry with their caption and a reference to the image in the photo library.

But I haven't been able to find any samples where I can do that. Just where you can pull up the existing photo library. Am I in a 'no soup for you' situation or can this be done? Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I presume this question is moribund but the book "Learning iPad Programming" (Turner/Harrington) has as a part of its tutorial the development of an app called "photoWheel" which covers a lot of what you're looking for. Make sure you get the 2nd ed, there's a lot of changes between iOS 5 (1st Ed) and iOS 6.

Note: it's not a fantastic book, but does likely cover much of what you're attempting to do while "developing" the app with the user.